# Stored procedure in java

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have a stored procedure which results in output as collection object as below.I am able to extract values of `[1,America,AA]` but values Bangkok and Canada are returned as one object and when I print I get `oracle.sql.ARRAY` as output.

Example :

```
1    
America    
AA    
Bangkok    
Canada
```

I have tried the below code :

```
if(Statement.getObject(Index)!=null){
    Data= (Object[]) ((Array) Statement.getObject(Index)).getArray();
    Object[] Data=null;
    Data= (Object[]) ((Array) Statement.getObject(Index)).getArray();
    int i=0;
    Struct row = (Struct) Data[i]; 
    for (Object attribute : row.getAttributes()){
        System.out.println(attribute.toString());
    }
}
```

Output :

```
1
America
AA
oracle.sql.ARRAY
```

Comment: your question is not clear.

Comment: I think he wants to know how to get `Bangkok` and `Canada` as individual attributes.

Comment: Please create a  [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), otherwise we will not be able to help.

Comment: Yes I need those attributes individually

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1):

That last attribute is obviously a oracle.sql.ARRAY datatype, so you need to get the array and process it separately.

```
if(Statement.getObject(Index)!=null){
    Data= (Object[]) ((Array) Statement.getObject(Index)).getArray();
    Object[] Data=null;
    Data= (Object[]) ((Array) Statement.getObject(Index)).getArray();
    int i=0;
    Struct row = (Struct) Data[i]; 
    for (Object attribute : row.getAttributes()){
        if (attribute instanceof oracle.sql.Array){
            // process the array, I didn't check this code YMMV
            String[] countries = (String[])attribute.getArray();
            for (String country : countries){
                System.out.println(country);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println(attribute.toString());
        }
    }
}
```